# How to center items of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have vertical `RecyclerView` with some elements, the `RecyclerView` takex up all screen size. I want to find a way to set items(from RecyclerView) on the vertical center of screen. How can I make it?

> I don't want use wrap_content for my `RecyclerView` and put it in the
> other view(with gravity=center)

[image]

Comment: you want the recycler view to be in the center or the items of the recycler to be located in the center of the each row?

Comment: it's hard to understand what you want. can you share the screenshot that you want to achieve

Comment: Post your code and explain clearly what you want

Comment: I want the items of recycler to be located in the center of the recycler view